# Cloud functions seem to bypass validation rules, but it shouldn't

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

```
    "connections-guests":{
      "$user_id":{
        "$to_user_id":{
          ".validate": "
            !root.child('/connections/' + $user_id + '/' + $to_user_id).exists()
          ",
          "score": {
              ".validate": "newData.val() * -1 <  now"
          },
          "$other": { ".validate": false }
        }
        }
    },
```

Apparently, on Cloud Functions, when I create this `connections-guests` node, it's always successful, regardless of `.validate`.

However, in the simulator (write: true for root) , validation rule is respected.

Comment: Likely answer below. If that's not it, share the code that is allowed to write and you think shouldn't.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you are accessing the database using the Admin SDK from within your Cloud Functions code. When you initialize the Admin SDK with its default settings it runs with full privilege and indeed bypasses the security rules.

If you don't want to run with administrative privilege, you can either [initialize the Admin SDK to run at lower privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45385431/firebase-rules-allowing-write-when-they-shouldnt-be/45385642#45385642), or you can [access the database through `event.data.ref`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42737203/some-firebase-security-rules-apply-for-admin-in-cloud-functions), which runs as the user who triggered the function.

Comment: `runs as the user who triggered the function.` -> does this mean the user who created the node that triggered the `onCreate` listener?

Comment: Yeah, that's what the docs say. I've never had the opportunity/need to try though, so let me know if it works differently.